# Is there a way to test change in children of React Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, children

I have a carousel component that I'm testing with Jest and Enzyme. The component receives as children any type of elements. On touchMove event depending on the direction of the touch the active child is changed accordingly.

Is there a way to test the behaviour of the component without depending on the implementation?

Comment: This depends on your case. Enzyme is best suited for tests that depend on the implementation. For blackbox testing try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-testing-library or keep DOM tests for e2e. It's possible that you won't be able to faithfully test DOM in Jest any way because it doesn't use real DOM.

Comment: Yes, don't write unit tests, write integration tests which execute in a browser instead. Unit tests are mostly useless for UI code (*imo*).

Comment: @Dominic even though I answered the question, I agree with you in most cases. I've added some more context to the bottom of my answer to address this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like wrap the children in containers, and set an `active` className on the active container.

```
// inside your carousel component's render function
{this.props.carouselItems.map((child, i) => 
  <div 
    className={
      'container' + 
      (i === this.state.activeIndex ? ' active' : '')
    }
  >
    {child}
  </div>
)}
```

Then, using selectors, verify with Enzyme that the correct *container* has the `active` class as you perform various actions / state changes.

That way it doesn't matter what the children components actually are, you've abstracted the test for 'activeness' away from a concrete implementation with specific children.

---

Note the above code using CSS classes is just a really simple example - you could also do this in a more 'React' way with components by using an `active` prop to a container component, even passing it to the `child` to do something with, etc. Whatever your usecase requires. The important concept is that you give mark each `child`'s container component for 'activeness' in some way so that Enzyme can test for that without having to test any concrete implementation of `child` itself.

Also note that unit tests by their nature do test implementation specifics at some level of abstraction. They have to. Using this method you can abstract above the level of your child components' specific implementation but you are still only testing the concrete mechanic of 'activeness' based on this container component pattern. What if that `active` class just doesn't do anything because the CSS is broken, or the way your `child` uses it is broken?

The usefulness of unit tests is quite limited when testing UI components, as you fundamentally can't get beyond testing concrete implementation details. Even using something like Jest snapshotting, you're just looking whether markup matches, not whether the markup is correct in the first place or displays correctly across different browsers. For UI, you really need to combine unit tests with automated functional and of course manual testing to really be sure you're actually testing if the component works for a *user*.